# Missing required position for __init__ method despite not implementing one

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm currently trying to create Models for my database in SQLAlchemy, but whenever I try to create my database I keep running into this error despite not even implementing an `__init__` function.

> TypeError: `__init__()` missing 1 required positional argument: 'item_type'

I'm sure I'm missing something stupid, but can someone point me in the right direction

Base Model:

```py
class EntityBase(db.Model):
    __abstract__ = True

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    date_created = db.Column(db.TIMESTAMP, nullable=False, default=lambda: datetime.now())
```

Inherited Model:

```py
class Recipe(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'Recipes'

    ingredients = db.Column(db.ARRAY, nullable=False)
    steps = db.Column(db.ARRAY, nullable=False)
    likes = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False, default=0)
    views = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False, default=0)
    title = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    description = db.Column(db.String)
```

StackTrace:

```
File "infrastructure\data\database_models\recipe.py", line 5, in <module>
    class Recipe(db.Model):
File "infrastructure\data\database_models\recipe.py", line 8, in Recipe
    ingredients = db.Column(db.ARRAY, nullable=False)
File "backend\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\schema.py", line 1565, in __init__
    super(Column, self).__init__(name, type_)
File "backend\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\elements.py", line 4640, in __init__
    self.type = type_api.to_instance(type_)
File "backend\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\type_api.py", line 1631, in to_instance
    return typeobj(*arg, **kw)
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'item_type'
```

Comment: The method is inherited from `db.Model`

Comment: Please post the full traceback.

Comment: Added stacktrace @Barmar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `db.ARRAY()` type requires the type of the array elements. So if `ingredients` is an array of integers, it would be:

```
ingredients = db.Column(db.ARRAY(db.Integer()), nullable=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the constructor from db.model has a required parameter.  Because your Recipe class is derived from db.model it must have a constructor that calls the super class and supplies this value.  This will also be true of anything derived from your EntityBase class.  The following is an example of how to properly do this.

```
class Recipe(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'Recipes'
    

    def __init__(self, item_type):
      super().__init__(item_type)
      ...
```

Comment: I don't understand why I need an __init__ method when the SQLAlchemy documentation doesn't use one

Comment: The error isn't happening in the `db.Model()` `__init__` method, it's happening in `ingredients = db.Column(db.ARRAY, nullable=False)`